# Complications in reading extra characters

Tags: c, windows, winapi, character-encoding

While using the default console font *Raster Fonts 8x12* I am unable to read extra characters using
`ReadConsoleOutputCharacter()`. These characters will be printed out as `?`.

---

If I change the console font to "Consolas" or "Lucida Console", these extra characters, read by
`ReadConsoleOutputCharacter()` are printed out without a problem.

---

Is there anything I can do about that?

Comment: You could start by being specific are you targeting unicode or ansi? What are "extra" characters.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Non-standard. These are in the range of 127-255.

Comment: Are you targeting Unicode or ANSI? Before announcing that you dislike MS shouldn't you try to understand the system?

Comment: These characters are printed okay just fine If I `putchar(218);` for example. But If I print out the buffer from `ReadConsoleOutputCharacter()` only regular characters are printed out, the rest is `?`. I am targeting to fix this.....

Comment: Why are you using ANSI? Are you still on Windows 98?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No... Windows 7..

Comment: So why are you using ANSI rather than Unicode?

Comment: How come I am using ANSI rather than Unicode? I am using what is it on default.

Comment: You talk of characters in the range 128-255. Which suggests 8 bit text. You ought to know what text encoding you are using.

Comment: I don't. Besides the point, I described the problem and I am looking for a fix.

Comment: It's not beside the point. But if you don't realise that then there's nothing we can do.

Comment: You mean, I can't fix it?

Comment: I mean you've given an incomplete problem description and refused to supply missing detail. Perhaps that's because you don't understand how text is handled by win32. Fine. In which case supply an MCVE.

Comment: All I know is that it defaults to UTF-8 encoding.
If I use `ReadConsoleOutputCharacter()` to copy for example the chars with dec(196) and then output them on screen, they appears as a '?' which is definitely not what I want.

Comment: That's unlikely. Windows tends not to use UTF-8. I'm done here anyway. I've made it clear what I think you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, I fixed it changing the locale after a conversion for a console I/O mapping:

```
    SetConsoleOutputCP(GetACP());
    SetConsoleCP(GetACP());
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

@David Heffernan
I suggest you to read [this](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/145590-non-english-characters-cout-2.html#post1086757)

Comment: No, you need to understand what the difference between ANSI and Unicode is and how it relates to the Windows API. The Windows API communicates in two modes: ANSI, which uses code pages and single-byte or two-byte encodings and is the source of those 128-255 characters that you're familiar with, and Unicode, which is a larger character set with more features and in Windows is always represented using a UTF-16 encoding and wide characters (those `L'x'` and `L"..."` things).

Comment: You clearly are stuck in the 128-255 character range mindset, so you expressed interest in communicating in ANSI. Fine. But you need to understand that ANSI is an [artifact title](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArtifactTitle) and that it can refer to all different types of character sets, which the code page tells you. You will need to know, and understand the characters that you want to read in and what they mean, because they mean entirely different things in different character sets.

Comment: Try it: write some extended ASCII characters (those 128-255 things) in different codepages and see how they differ. In particular, use a Cyrillic codepage (Russian, et al). Most modern Windows programs *don't* use ANSI because this whole code page nonsense is too inconvenient and the Internet doesn't use ANSI much anymore (if at all). If you want to make the jump to Unicode like the rest of us, then you will need to learn about the differences and how to work in Unicode.

Comment: I am trying to understand, but everything sounds so confusing and arguing itself. I am not a native speaker. There is no such information provided on my language. The least thing I can do is search for more detailed source, with easier words.

Comment: The easiest way is to drop all your knowledge of locales and code pages and switch to Unicode APIs by defining both `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` before including `<windows.h>` and using `TCHAR` and the `TEXT()` or `_T()` macros around literal strings and characters. Your program will now magically work, and if you for whatever Cthulhu-provided reason need to switch back to ANSI can do so without making any drastic changes. [Try this for more information.](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=windows+unicode+programming&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: Okay then. What is your native language? Please don't spark an argument with the people trying to help; that's the easiest way to NOT get the help. Next time, I suggest starting with this information; it would have avoided a lot of the arguments.

Comment: I have no knowledge in code pages and locales.. Bulgarian is my native language.

Comment: Okay. I personally don't know any other Bulgarians but I'm sure at least one other one is here who can explain things to you. (I find it unusual that there would be a lack of this information in other languages; at the same time, it IS a problem...). Good luck :/ (and I apologize if what I just said above sounded too aggressive)

Comment: No, it didn't. But I am just literally too confused to be morally-straight. Anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> This function uses either Unicode characters or 8-bit characters from
>   the console's current code page. The console's code page defaults
>   initially to the system's OEM code page. To change the console's code
>   page, use the SetConsoleCP or SetConsoleOutputCP functions, or use the
>   chcp or mode con cp select= commands.

I believe you're getting back a unicode string that needs to be encoded to a charset before trying to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I personally dislike Microsoft and their everything. So how can I fix this. Using `SetConsoleOutputCP`? Its reference is extremely confusing and forces me to use one googolplex of other functions.

Comment: try `SetConsoleCP(1252)` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for list of standard windows code pages)

Comment: With 1252 it doesn't even print out non-standard characters directly with `putchar` for e.g. And yes I tested a few, but with no success.